# JavaScript difference between ' ' and (' ')

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `''` and `('')`

```
let n = 'a' + 1

let n = ('a') + 1

let n = ('a') + (1)
```

what is the difference?

Comment: There is no difference!

Comment: Just like between `10` and `(10)` in math...

Comment: there is no one. parentheses with a single value makes no sense, but does not harm either.

Comment: no diferance, () takes first order only to process

Comment: The parentheses help you to see the expressions easier.

Comment: Put `('') == ''` into your console and it will return `true`

Comment: no difference. anywhere you have 'a1' and type will STRING.

Comment: `()` are used for changing the order of execution with lower precedence [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). if the statements are in the same order then the parenthesis are of no use.

Comment: @NinaScholz Unless that single value is an object literal or function expression at the beginning of a statement... `{x: 1}.x` would throw a nice SyntaxError, but `({x: 1}).x` wouldn't.

Comment: See [MDN Grouping Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping). Another slight difference is that `let a; (a) = function(){}; console.log(a.name);` would return `""`, but without the grouping it would return `"a"` because `(a) = function(){}` doesn’t quite follow the assignment expression syntax that would result in a `NamedEvaluation`.

Answer (score 8):

They are same both.

`()` is important for precedence especially if there is math operations and concat with string together. [Read this info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

```js
var example1='x' + (1+2); console.log(example1);
var example2='x'+1+2; console.log(example2);

var example3=("x"+4)/2; console.log(example3);
var example4=("x")+(4/2); console.log(example4);
```

Comment: Just like BODMAS in Maths.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a property from an object works without parentheses.

```js
var value = { x: 1 }.x;

console.log(value);
```

Basically the only need for parenthesis is to destructure the item ouside of a declaration.

**Does not work**

```js
var foo;

{ foo } = { foo: 1 }; // assigment to a block statement

console.log(foo);
```

**Works**

```js
var foo;

({ foo } = { foo: 1 });

console.log(foo);
```

Another use case for parentheses, is by takeing an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which returns an object.

```js
var fn = foo => ({ foo });

console.log(fn(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

There’s no difference between `''` and `('')`. Parentheses make no difference in your code examples.

Parentheses `()`, known as the [Grouping Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping), are used to **change the order of evaluation of an expression**. Consider the following expression:

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

As the `*` operator has higher precedence, first `2 * 3` will be evaluated and then the result of multiplication will be added to `1`.

```js
const result = 1 + 2 * 3;

console.log(result);
```

If you want to do addition first, then you can use `()`.

```
(1 + 2) * 3
```

Adding parentheses will change how the expression is evaluated. Instead of multiplication, now `1 + 2` will be evaluated first and then the result of addition will be multiplied with `3`.

```js
const result = (1 + 2) * 3;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Grouping Operator ()**

Grouping operator implies the precedence of evaluation of an expression or subexpression.

With the grouping operator, it is possible to override the normal precedence of evaluation by telling the compiler an expression with lower precedence should be evaluated before an expression with higher priority.

> ```
> console.log(3 + 4 * 5); // 3 + 20
> // expected output: 23
>
> console.log(4 * 3 ** 2); // 4 * 9
> // expected output: 36
>
> let a;
> let b;
>
> console.log(a = b = 5);
> // expected output: 5
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence